# Flying Saucer: itext html to pdf conversion taking long time offline

Tags: itext, flying-saucer

I used Flying Saucer library to convert html to pdf. It used to work fine if the system is connected to internet. But if system is not connected to internet then it is taking around 5 minutes. Is there any parameter through which i can stop itextrenderer to look for images online.

Below is the method i used to convert HTML to PDF :

```
LOGGER.info("Converting HTML To PDF.");
OutputStream os = null;
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(finalOutputFilePath);
    final Document cleanedDocument = HtmlUtil.cleanHTML(finalInputFilePath);
    final ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    final String url = new File(finalInputFilePath).toURI().toURL().toString();
    renderer.setDocument(cleanedDocument, url);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
    LOGGER.info("HTML is converted To PDF.");
} finally {
    if (null != os) {
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your document have images?

Comment: Yes my document contains images.

Comment: If you'd use iText's XML Worker instead of Flying Saucer, you'd be able to implement the `ImageProvider` of the parser and cache images so that you don't have to download the same image over and over again. Flying Saucer is a third party project not endorsed by the iText Group; we can't comment on that project. We don't even know if it's still supported.

Comment: Flying saucer does contain a image cache but being offline shouldnt affect that. I would suspect that its not the images that are taking a long time but instead the DTD as defined in the doctype declaration of your HTML. You might debug your application and see what part is taking so long .